Handling Lookup Fields with Multiple Object Types in SOQL for a Custom LWC
I'm developing a Lightning Web Component (LWC) where users can select a root object and then choose fields they want to query. Some of these fields are lookup fields, which means they might need to select fields from the related objects as well.
The issue I'm facing is that some lookup fields can reference multiple object types. For example, the "Owner" field can point to either a User or a Group. When I include fields in my SOQL query that exist on one object type but not the other (e.g., DeveloperName or RelatedId), the query fails with an error because the field doesn't exist on all possible related objects.
Here’s an example:

What I want to achieve is to run the SOQL query without getting errors when a field doesn’t exist on the related object. Instead of the query failing, I want to get the data for the fields that do exist and ignore any errors for missing fields.
I understand that I could run separate queries for each field and object type, but this is not an efficient solution, especially when dealing with bulk operations. I need a "bulkified" approach that allows me to query all the fields at once and handle any missing fields gracefully.
I’ve already reviewed this related question, but the suggested solution involves checking if the field exists before querying, which doesn't suit my needs.
How can I execute a dynamic SOQL query that ignores missing fields and returns the data for the fields that are present?
Thank you for your insights!

To correctly query Polymorphic fields (field which could point of one of many objects), you need to use typeof clause. You need to construct the query like this depending on if selected field exists in the object or not.
For ex.,
SELECT 
  TYPEOF What
    WHEN Account THEN Phone, NumberOfEmployees
    WHEN Opportunity THEN Amount, CloseDate
    ELSE Name, Email
  END
FROM Event

